# How do I create a MongoDB aggregate to lookup and add fields using ObjectIds in array objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate, lookup

Using Mongo 4.4

I'm looking to to lookups across collections and add a human readable value from the target collection to the source collection using a aggregate.

This works fine for individual values, but for some lookups the ObjectIds are in objects in arrays, and I can't get that work.  I can pull all the values back, but not place the individual values in the array objects.

In this test case, I have a library database with a **books** collection and a **subscribers** collection.  The subscribers have a **checkouts** entry with is an array of objects, containing a reference to a book, and the checkout date.  I want to add the book title to each object in the array.

Test Database:

books collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208c9f0d97eff0cfbefde6"),
    "title" : "There and back again",
    "author" : "Bilbo Baggins",
    "publisher" : "Middle Earth Books"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208cd10d97eff0cfbeff02"),
    "title" : "Two Towers",
    "author" : "JRR Tolkin",
    "publisher" : "Dude Books"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208cf10d97eff0cfbeffa3"),
    "title" : "Dune",
    "author" : "Frank Herbert",
    "publisher" : "Classic Books"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208d1d0d97eff0cfbf0087"),
    "title" : "Old Man's War",
    "author" : "John Scalzi",
    "publisher" : "Old Man Books"
  }
]
```

subscribers collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208c2e0d97eff0cfbefb46"),
    "name" : "Tom",
    "checkouts" : [ 
        {
            "bookId" : ObjectId("63208cd10d97eff0cfbeff02"),
            "checkoutDate" : ISODate("2022-01-01T21:21:20.202Z")
        }, 
        {
            "bookId" : ObjectId("63208d1d0d97eff0cfbf0087"),
            "checkoutDate" : ISODate("2022-01-02T21:22:20.202Z")
        }
    ],
    "address" : "123 Somewhere"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208c4e0d97eff0cfbefc1f"),
    "name" : "Bob",
    "checkouts" : [],
    "address" : "123 Somewhere"
  }, 
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208c640d97eff0cfbefc9a"),
    "name" : "Mary",
    "checkouts" : [],
    "address" : "123 Somewhere Else"
  }
```

Desired Output for user Tom:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208c2e0d97eff0cfbefb46"),
    "name" : "Tom",
    "checkouts" : [ 
        {
            "bookId" : ObjectId("63208cd10d97eff0cfbeff02"),
            "checkoutDate" : ISODate("2022-01-01T21:21:20.202Z"),
            "title" :  "Two Towers"
        }, 
        {
            "bookId" : ObjectId("63208d1d0d97eff0cfbf0087"),
            "checkoutDate" : ISODate("2022-01-02T21:22:20.202Z"),
            "title" : "Old Man's War"
        }
    ],
    "address" : "123 Somewhere",
}
```

Using this aggregate:

```
db.getCollection('subscribers').aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: ObjectId("63208c2e0d97eff0cfbefb46") } },
  {$lookup: {from: "books", localField: "checkouts.bookId", foreignField: "_id", as: "book_tmp_field" }},
  {$addFields: { "checkouts.title": "$book_tmp_field.title"}},
  {$project: { book_tmp_field: 0}}

])
```

This is the closest I can get:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63208c2e0d97eff0cfbefb46"),
    "name" : "Tom",
    "checkouts" : [ 
        {
            "bookId" : ObjectId("63208cd10d97eff0cfbeff02"),
            "checkoutDate" : ISODate("2022-01-01T21:21:20.202Z"),
            "title" : [ 
                "Two Towers", 
                "Old Man's War"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "bookId" : ObjectId("63208d1d0d97eff0cfbf0087"),
            "checkoutDate" : ISODate("2022-01-02T21:22:20.202Z"),
            "title" : [ 
                "Two Towers", 
                "Old Man's War"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "address" : "123 Somewhere"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before performing the lookup, you should `UNWIND` the `checkouts` array. After all the processing is done, group the documents, to obtain the `checkouts` in the array. Finally, project your desired output document. Like this:

```
db.subscribers.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("63208c2e0d97eff0cfbefb46")
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$checkouts"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "books",
      localField: "checkouts.bookId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "book_tmp_field"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "checkouts.title": "$book_tmp_field.title"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      book_tmp_field: 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        _id: "$_id",
        address: "$address",
        name: "$name"
      },
      "checkouts": {
        "$push": "$checkouts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$_id",
          {
            checkouts: "$checkouts"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HBM8-OBevYK).

Comment: Added a  ``` {
    "$unwind": "$checkouts.title"
  },
``` 
after the addFields step, but that got me what I wanted